# JSP Application Scope settings for Database Query

Tags: java, jsp

I want to store query result in `HashMap` for each "service" parameter passed from another class and then store them to application scope by `application.setAttribute()` and if service exist in application scope  I could get those values from  `application.getAttribute()`. There are 3 columns to be stored for each service.  How can I get those 3 Column values depending upon services parameter if they exist in application scope? Please suggest how to store values in application scope (If I am doing wrong in the following code).

```
 service=request.getParameter("service");   
 Map<String,String> FreetextMap=new HashMap<String,String>();

if(application.getAttribute(service)==null )
{
query = "SELECT aUnique,aTitle,aBody FROM FreeTexts WHERE service='" +service+ "'     
rs = DBUtils.getRs(con,query);
if (rs.next()) {
clientFreetextMap.put("unique", rs.getString("aUnique"));
clientFreetextMap.put("body",rs.getString("aBody"));
clientFreetextMap.put("txt",rs.getString("aTitle"));
application.setAttribute(service,clientFreetextMap);

 }
```

The following code is responsible for getting values from application scope but it's not able to as I know I am missing something to declare services. I am not having idea where to write service?? How to get values with respect to service parameter??

```
    else 
     {
   txt=(String) application.getAttribute(clientFreetextMap.get("txt"));
   uniqueid=(String) application.getAttribute(clientFreetextMap.get("unique"));
   adsbody=(String) application.getAttribute(clientFreetextMap.get("body"));
     }
```

Comment: This code suffers from a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability. Don't build queries by concatenating strings. Use `PreparedStatement`s instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the `clientFreetextMap` itself in the `if` block. You should get the same `Map` out in the `else` block, then get the data you need from that. Try something like this:

```
clientFreetextMap = (Map)application.getAttribute(service);
txt = clientFreetextMap.get("txt");
uniqueid = clientFreetextMap.get("unique");
adsbody = clientFreetextMap.get("body");
```

Comment: @Joe.. So, after it sets to application scope.. next time it doesn't do Database Query isn't it? so I hope it will boost the performance!